# UINavigationController pushes several of the same viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UIButton in my app that when pressed it shows the next view controller. Sometimes the UI locks up and the app freezes for a moment due to background processes. When this happens the user might tap the button multiple times because nothing happened immediately on the first tap, and when this occurs the UINavigationController pushes the ViewController again a bunch of times on top of itself, so that you have to go back several times to get back to home. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.pushVCButton.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
}

- (IBAction)pushVCButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.pushVCButton.enabled = NO;
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    self.pushVCButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

How do I get this to never push multiple instances of viewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really try to make the background process run not on UI thread, but if you can not try setting the button enabled to yes only when view did disappear or listen for completion of push animation:

```
- (IBAction)pushVCButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    self.pushVCButton.enabled = NO;
    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    // Hack: wait for this view to disappear to enable the button
    //self.pushVCButton.enabled = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated]
    self.pushVCButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

Also make sure that the action is not called twice.